# Algebraic simplification of y=mx+b

Tags: linear-algebra

For a few things I've been working on recently I've needed to write equations of lines algebraically, mainly in slope-intercept form $$y=mx+b.$$ If I have two points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$, calculating the value of $m$ algebraically is easy:

$$m=\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}$$

The problem I'm having is calculating the value of $b$ algebraically. We can say that

$$b=y-mx$$

But we cant sub that value of $b$ back into $y=mx+b$, you'd end up with $y=mx+y-mx$ which gets you the eloquent $y=y$.

What am I doing wrong here? How else could I algebraically write the value of $b$? Should I just use a different equation of a line like point-slope form (and if so how would I derive the value of $b$ from a different form)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can plug any known point into the equation $y = mx + b$ to find $b$. Using the point $(x_1, y_1)$ that you used in finding $m$, you have
\begin{equation}
b = y_1 - mx_1
\end{equation}
where $m$ is the expression you've provided.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Thanks for clearing that up!

Answer (score 1):

An equation for the line is
$$\frac{y-y_1}{x-x_1}=\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_2}.$$
Now if $x=0$ then $y=b$, that is
$$b=y_1-x_1\cdot\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_2}.$$