# determining accurate points on x/y graph with fractions

Tags: linear-algebra, slope

I have the following 2 points and need to find other points along this line and the y- intercept.

$$\left(-\frac13, \frac54\right), \left(\frac12, \frac34\right)$$

I have determined the slope $m = -\frac56.$

If these were whole numbers I could just find points using the slope, but these are fractions of differing denominators. How should I go about calculating accurate points. Thanks.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/598483/algebraic-simplification-of-y-mxb?rq=1

Comment: What is $m$? The slope?

Comment: The equation of the line is
$$
12x + 20y = 21
$$
if that helps ...

Comment: So what do you mean by "accurate points"? Aren't the ones you wrote accurate points?

Comment: Also, take a look at the equation of the line, and let's say that we are interested in integer solutions ($x$ and $y$ are both integers). If we take mod 2 on both sides, we get
$$
0 \equiv 1 \mod{2}
$$
which doesn't have any solutions. Another way of saying this is that the left-hand side is always even and the right-hand side is always odd. Therefore, there are no integer points on the line.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the points are not given as whole numbers has no effect on the calculation.

You have the equation

$$y=mx+n$$

and you have two pairs of $x, y$ that you know you can plug into the equation.

You can calculate $m$ as the difference in the $y$ values, divided by the difference in $x$-values. You should re-do your calculation, because the result is **not** $-\frac56$. I don't know where you made the mistake, because you didn't provide the method by which you calculated $-\frac56$, but the result is wrong. If you want help with where your result is wrong, please first show how you got to it.

Once you calculated $m$, just plug in one of the numbers and calculate $n$.

Comment: 5xum - I redid the calculation after your comment. It should  be - 3/5, thank you. M = y2-y1/x2-x1